# Disable copying In[n] or Out[n] when clicking on it in a notebook

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization

When I left-click on something like `In[1]` in the margin of a notebook (as appears when running a Cell) it automatically gets copied to the clipboard so that if I paste I get `In[1]` instead of what was previously there. How can I disable this? (I accidentally click on `In` or `Out` much more often than I actually want to use this feature.)

---

Version: "12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

---

Screenshot for clarification:

[image]

The text `In[849]:=` gets copied to the clipboard if I left-click on `In[849]:=`. I pasted it in the cell below to visualize this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on macOS. Can you be more specific about what you do to trigger copying?

Comment: @Szabolcs, I thought this would be universal. Perhaps it only happens on Linux. I clarified it as much as I can now, but if you can't reproduce it I think it is more likely that your Mathematica is not showing the same behavior as mine.

Comment: No, I still cannot reproduce it on macOS. I cannot test this on Linux at the moment. I can only copy it by first left-clicking, then right-clicking and choosing "Copy".

Comment: Ok. For me just left clicking automatically copies it to the clipboard.

Comment: Cannot replicate this on 12.2.0 Win x64. I have to press Ctrl-C when the In[..]:= part highlights otherwise it is not copied to the clipboard.